# Remote testing Coded UI from Visual Studio throws "connection was actively refused"

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, mstest

I am attempting to run tests on a remote agent by using a test controller that is on the same remote machine.  I have set up my TestSettings file as follows:

```
<RemoteController name="MachineName" />
<Execution location="Remote">
    <AgentRule name="AllAgentsDefaultRole">
    </AgentRule>
```

When I tell MSTest to execute a selected test in release or debug mode, it successfully builds the project and then returns `"Failed to queue test run 'run name': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."`  Visual Studio 2013 has been installed on the controller/agent machine, and the agent, controller, and client can all communicate successfully.  Default ports are being used for communication (6901 and 6910), and telnet is able to connect.  How do I get the test executing successfully?

Comment: Have this exact same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: It looks like you cross posted this on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489997/executing-test-on-remote-agent-fails-with-target-machine-actively-refused-it.  Can you add the answer here as well?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Agents cannot debug remotely, and while the build I was executing against in the above post was "release" (in one instance), I was still attempting to debug. If I select the test and click "Run" instead, it executes successfully on the remote agent.